# background loop problem

Tags: bash

I'm in process of extending my knowledge of bash scripting. I came across following snippet:

```
!/bin/bash
# background-loop.sh

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10            # First loop. 
do
  echo -n "$i "
done & # Run this loop in background.
   # Will sometimes execute after second loop.

echo   # This 'echo' sometimes will not display.

for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20   # Second loop.
do
  echo -n "$i "
done  

echo word   # This 'echo' sometimes will not display.
```

It seems that this snippet output is non deterministic; and I would like to know why...

edit: so far; in 10 attempts "word" was always shown

edit2:
sample outputs:

```
11 1 12 13 14 2 15 3 16 4 17 5 18 6 19 7 20 8 9 word
1 11 12 13 2 14 3 15 4 16 5 17 6 18 7 19 8 20 9 10 word
11 12 13 14 1 15 16 17 2 18 3 19 4 20 5 6 word
```

Comment: The "echo   # This 'echo' sometimes will not display." is going to be a problem.  Each a real word, not a blank line.  You can't see a blank line echoing, so you think nothing is happening.   After changing the echo, please **update** your question to include the actual log of an actual example of the actual error.

Comment: turn on your debugging `set -vx`, I bet you see all the commands getting executed.

Comment: @shellter I executer 'set -vx ' and then run script; I had same result non determistic, except seeing name of script that I ran

Comment: Free hint: Use the `seq(1)` command: `for i in $(seq 1 10); do` Note that BSD systems don't have `seq(1)` but have `jot(1)` which behaves almost exactly the same ... It's one of those great inter-UNIX(-like) incompatibilities :-(

Comment: Free hint #2: If you don't use specific bash extensions to the bourne shell (And the above script doesn't), set the hashbang to `#!/bin/sh`, /bin/bash may not always be available.

Comment: @bbaja42 : Thanks, adding the output you found confusing improves the quality of the answers you get.  Your comments embedded in the code  # This 'echo' sometimes will not display. where confusing to me.  **I agree with both patjon and larsmans.**

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Why use `seq` (an external program) when you can `{1..10}`?  AND bash is available almost anywhere except for certain embedded systems  AND the user has tagged his question with `bash` - why are you proselytizing for another religion?

Comment: I didn't know about the `{1..10}` syntax, I assume this is some bash specific construct? ... `/bin/bash` is not "available almost everywhere", it's available on Linux. It's not available on any of the BSD operating systems for example. If you don't use bash syntax, you might as well call `/bin/sh` IMHO and if you do use bash it's better to call `/usr/bin/env bash` because bash may not live in `/bin/` ... I'm not "proselytizing for another religion", that is your assumption ... I just noticed these two things ... Other opinions welcome ...

Comment: For reference, the original seems to come from the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BGLOOP).

I believe you can actually see the empty echo execute: It prints a newline.  It's definitely confusing, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what is happening here is that you have 2 processes running at the same time. And as always in such case you cannot predict in which order they will execute. Every combination of output from first `for` loop and second `for` loop is possible.

Answer (score 4):

A loop, or any command, that runs in the background is run concurrently with the rest of the script. It might run on a different processor if you have a multi-core machine. The order in which things are depends on your number of cores, how busy the system is and the whims of the operating system scheduler.

With large amounts of I/O from multiple processes to the same terminal/file/whatever, you might even see outputs being mixed up.

Comment: But why would one of the 'echo' commands not display?  The comment "This 'echo' sometimes will not display" comes from the original snippet in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BGLOOP), but it doesn't explain why :(

Answer (score 0):

You can wait on bg tasks in scripts as follows:

```
# create a sentinel for exiting (is this the right term?)
export sentinel=".stopBgTask.$$"
# Run in the background and wait for sentinel to be created
i=1
while [ ! -e "$sentinel" ]
do echo $i
   i=$(($i + 1))
   sleep 1
done & # uncomment the & when you have no script errors

echo "Parent sleeping for a few seconds"
sleep 3
echo "stop the background task" > $sentinel
echo "Waiting for bg task to end..."
wait $! # wait for last bg task to end (kill $! would work too)
rm $sentinel
echo "We are done!"
```